# create Mat from a pointer

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a fancy camera with global shutter that has its own set of API's. What I have been trying to do is to initialize the camera and trigger the shutter in a precise timed loop. The camera API then returns a pointer to the first pixel of the image (let's call it image.bp).

My code looks something like this:

```
XI_IMG image; //image type specified by the manufacturer. the image.bp points to the first pixel of the image
camera initialization ...
for(;;){
    xiGetImage(xiH, timeOut, &image); //API given by the camera manufacturer
    Mat frame(image.height, image.width, CV_8U, image.bp);
    imshow(window_name,frame);
}
```

Now this code WORKS. But what I have been trying to do is define "frame" as Mat before the for loop so I don't end up redefining it every cycle (correct me if I'm wrong but redefining it in every loop would be very inefficient). But everything that I have tried fails.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: `correct me if I'm wrong but redefining it in every loop would be very inefficient` You are probably wrong, modern compilers can optimize the penalty away. Even if there were a penalty, you should only change it if it is clearly affecting your application's speed after profiling.

Comment: I don't see any particular issue with what I got at the moment. Just wanted to see if there a different method that I could use for comparison. In this case, I don't mind being wrong. Just makes my life easier. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Btw, one more question that's been bothering me. Do I need to do a frame.release() after imshow or not? Thanks

Comment: [Apparently not](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=mat#mat-release) `since this method is automatically called in the destructor, or by any other method that changes the data pointer, it is usually not needed.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `frame.data` (the `Mat::data` member) that you could re-assign every time you acquire a new frame using your `xiGetImage` code. When you do so, make sure you initialise your `frame` object using a  valid image pointer, rather than omitting the last parameter. That way, your `Mat` object will not allocate own memory (and eventually leak it).

```
XI_IMG image; //image type specified by the manufacturer. the image.bp points to the first pixel of the image camera initialization ...

xiGetImage(xiH, timeOut, &image); //API given by the camera manufacturer
Mat frame(image.height, image.width, CV_8U, image.bp);

for(;;){
    xiGetImage(xiH, timeOut, &image); //API given by the camera manufacturer
    frame.data = image.bp;
    imshow(window_name,frame);
}
```

Further,

1. I guess the comments regarding compiler optimisers are correct to a certain extend too. Your `Mat` constructor will only allocate the stack-allocated part, and will not do any heap allocation (as you specified your own data pointer). As the stack-allocated part is exactly the same size for every frame, I would assume the compiler will at least re-use the same address. There will probably be some overhead in setting the width and height for every frame, but that's really minimal effort.
2. I highly suspect that the address pointer in `image.bp` is stable and does not change every frame. Drivers prefer to reuse pre-allocated memory, rather than fragment the heap. If that's the case, you could even omit the line `frame.data = image.bp;` above.